# PySide2 signals aren't received in slots of a worker after `moveToThread`

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside2

I'm having trouble making slots receiving signals after a worker class has been `moveToThread`.
The goal is that the slots inside the worker will be executed on another thread.

This is my test worker class:

```py
class DbWorker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: DbWorker instantiated...")

    @Slot(str)
    def test_slot_str(self, test_text: str):
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: test_slot_str fired. Got Message '{test_text}'")

    @Slot()
    def test_slot_empty(self):
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: test_slot_empty fired ")

    @Slot()
    def process(self):
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: Process slot activated!")
```

When I execute this:

```py
# Signals must inherit QObject
class Communicate(QObject):
    signal_str = Signal(str)
    signal_empty = Signal()


def moveToThreadTest():
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main started...")
    worker = DbWorker()
    communicate = Communicate()
    my_thread = QThread()
    worker.moveToThread(my_thread)

    communicate.signal_str.connect(worker.test_slot_str)
    communicate.signal_empty.connect(worker.test_slot_empty)
    my_thread.started.connect(worker.process)
    my_thread.start()

    communicate.signal_str.emit("test")
    communicate.signal_empty.emit()
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main thread end...")
```

The output I'm getting is output:

```
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:35 -     moveToThreadTest() ]   13824: main started... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:12 -             __init__() ]   13824: DbWorker instantiated... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:48 -     moveToThreadTest() ]   13824: main thread end... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:25 -              process() ]   20776: Process slot activated!
```

So the slot that's connected to `my_thread.started` manages to execute from another thread. But none o the other slots do the same. Also, it's worth pointing out that the last line is printed only if I run this code without debugging. If I run in debug mode, I get this:

```
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:35 -     moveToThreadTest() ]   25128: main started... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:12 -             __init__() ]   25128: DbWorker instantiated... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:48 -     moveToThreadTest() ]   25128: main thread end...
```

I tried to see if I connect the signals to slots in a correct way so I ran the same example without moving the worker to a thread like so:

```py
def withoutMoveToThread():
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main started...")
    communicate = Communicate()
    worker = DbWorker()
    communicate.signal_str.connect(worker.test_slot_str)
    communicate.signal_empty.connect(worker.test_slot_empty)
    communicate.signal_str.emit("Signal str")
    communicate.signal_empty.emit()
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main finished...")
```

And it seems to work just fine:

```
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:52 -  withoutMoveToThread() ]   6052: main started... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:12 -             __init__() ]   6052: DbWorker instantiated... 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:16 -        test_slot_str() ]   6052: test_slot_str fired. Got Message 'Signal str' 
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:20 -      test_slot_empty() ]   6052: test_slot_empty fired  
 - INFO     [db_worker.py:59 -  withoutMoveToThread() ]   6052: main finished...
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong and why are my slots not receiving the connected signals. Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the full example file:

```py
import threading

from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtCore import QObject, Slot, Signal, QThread

from logger import logger


class DbWorker(QObject):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: DbWorker instantiated...")

    @Slot(str)
    def test_slot_str(self, test_text: str):
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: test_slot_str fired. Got Message '{test_text}'")

    @Slot()
    def test_slot_empty(self):
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: test_slot_empty fired ")

    @Slot()
    def process(self):
        # print("Process Activated!")
        logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: Process slot activated!")


# Signals must inherit QObject
class Communicate(QObject):
    signal_str = Signal(str)
    signal_empty = Signal()


def moveToThreadTest():
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main started...")
    worker = DbWorker()
    communicate = Communicate()
    my_thread = QThread()
    worker.moveToThread(my_thread)

    communicate.signal_str.connect(worker.test_slot_str)
    communicate.signal_empty.connect(worker.test_slot_empty)
    my_thread.started.connect(worker.process)
    my_thread.start()

    communicate.signal_str.emit("test")
    communicate.signal_empty.emit()
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main thread end...")


def withoutMoveToThread():
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main started...")
    communicate = Communicate()
    worker = DbWorker()
    communicate.signal_str.connect(worker.test_slot_str)
    communicate.signal_empty.connect(worker.test_slot_empty)
    communicate.signal_str.emit("Signal str")
    communicate.signal_empty.emit()
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main finished...")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    withoutMoveToThread()
```

Comment: The `withoutMoveToThread` "works" just because the connection is *direct*, and it results in directly calling the connected slots. In your other example there are two problems: you're not creating a QCoreApplication (nor running its event loop) and all objects created in that functions are garbage collected as soon as it returns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signals need the event loop to work, in your case you must create a QCoreApplication:

```py
def moveToThreadTest():
    app = QCoreApplication.instance()
    if app is None:
        app = QCoreApplication()
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main started...")
    worker = DbWorker()
    communicate = Communicate()
    my_thread = QThread()
    worker.moveToThread(my_thread)

    communicate.signal_str.connect(worker.test_slot_str)
    communicate.signal_empty.connect(worker.test_slot_empty)
    my_thread.started.connect(worker.process)
    my_thread.start()

    communicate.signal_str.emit("test")
    communicate.signal_empty.emit()
    logger.info(f"{threading.get_ident()}: main thread end...")

    app.exec_()
```

And change `threading.get_ident()` by `threading.current_thread()` you get:

```
INFO:140406642902848: main started...
INFO:<_MainThread(MainThread, started 140406642902848)>: DbWorker instantiated...
INFO:140406642902848: main thread end...
INFO:<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140406565365312)>: Process slot activated!
INFO:<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140406565365312)>: test_slot_str fired. Got Message 'test'
INFO:<_DummyThread(Dummy-1, started daemon 140406565365312)>: test_slot_empty fire
```

In your initial case (which partially works) it happens that there was time to create the thread but since the function is terminated instantly then the object is also destroyed.